# Adding JTextField as an array to GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jtextfield

I want to ask about how to add `JTextFields` by putting them together in an array (a for loop would be useful) and then `setBounds` (using absolute layout [or null]).

For example I want to create three `JTextFields` in my for loop, where the X of `setBounds` have to be something like 50, then 100 and then 150. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use null layouts/setBounds
2. To set the size of the text field, pass an integer to the constructor specifying character columns `new JTextField(15)`
3. Choose a proper layout managers, and let *it* do the positioning for you. For example, if you want a grid of 4x4 text fields, you can use a `GridLayout(4, 4)`

   ```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
   JTextField[][] fields = new JTextField[4][4];
   ....
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
           JTextField jtf = new JTextField(15);
           fields[i][j] = jtf;
           panel.add(jtf);
       }
   }
   ```

   <sub>Note: I use the 2D array you will be easily able to reference the fields</sub>

---

You should have a look at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to see what other layout managers are available and learn how they work.

Comment: The reason for I use setBounds is that I have to use my center panel for different things hence I thought that would be easier regard this. Maybe I am totally wrong?

Comment: +1, `Maybe I am totally wrong?` Yes. `I have to use my center panel for different things` - then maybe you should be using a `CardLayout`. See the tutorial link given above for more information.